# Favorite tags in new navigation

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, new-nav

Currently, when I view questions by my favorite tags, I only see two tags in the list. But I have 5 favorite tags:

[image]

How can I get all of my favorite tags into the search list, so I don't have to keep typing them?

Comment: OK, that is particularly odd! I'm current looking into multiple new-nav bugs, so will investigate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this is rolling out. The new nav code was unfortunately re-using parts of the unanswered my tags tab (which was broken as well), since it was using an old tag preference storage mechanism.

Comment: Works for me now!