# Favorite tags in new navigation, everything is white

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching, new-nav

As a followup to my question [yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261977/297908), now I can get my favorite tags to work correctly from the drop-down. However, now questions which match multiple tags don't get colored.

Looking at just C++, the third question down is colored yellow because templates is another one of my favorite tags:

[image]

But not so if I'm looking at all of my favorites - everything just shows up as bland white:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The highlighting excludes any favorite tags that are in your current filter. In the c++ tag on you screenshot only the question with the template tag is highlighted. Otherwise your whole screen would be yellow.

Comment: Why not highlight those that match at least 2 tags?

Comment: What about users that only have 1 favorite tag? Plus, if you use the `all` combinator, that's _every_ question.

Comment: Why not just color none of them in both cases? That would make sense to me.

Comment: @Barry if you want it changed, go create a feature request. This is the way it has always been, not a bug in [tag:new-nav]

Comment: [Ok](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262209/297908), didn't realize that was by-design.