# Highlight questions matching multiple favorites when searching for all favorites

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

When I search by one custom favorite tag, say [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), questions that match other favorite tags of mine show up colored yellow:

[image]

But now that I can easily search for *any* of my favorite tags, I do that regularly, but *all* of the questions show up as white:

[image]

Can we change the highlighting such that if I am search for *any* of multiple favorite tags, any questions that match multiple favorite tags get highlighted?